# gradlew "Unable to open connection to ADB server: java.io.IOException: Can't find ADB server on port 5037"

Tags: react-native, android-studio, gradle, adb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Currently trying to set up my environment to develop React Native in WSL2 using Android Studio installed in Windows 11. I know that this is possible because I did it on my last laptop... however, when I execute `npx react-native run-android` the build hangs at 97% on **app:installDebug.** Reading through the log messages above, it seems that there is a problem with adb:

```
info Starting JS server...
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.
info Installing the app...
01:23:35 D/DeviceMonitor: Opening adb connection
01:23:35 D/DeviceMonitor: Opening adb connection
01:23:35 D/DeviceMonitor: Unable to open connection to ADB server: java.io.IOException: Can't find adb server on port 5037, IPv4 attempt: Connection refused, IPv6 attempt: Connection refused

...

> Task :app:installDebug
```

Basically, the adb server keeps restarting over and over. Running `adb kill-server && adb start-server` doesn't fix this, for obvious reasons. I realized that this log message comes from gradle, as this is the full output of `./gradlew` in the `project/android` directory:

```
01:22:36 D/DeviceMonitor: Opening adb connection
01:22:36 D/DeviceMonitor: Opening adb connection
01:22:36 D/DeviceMonitor: Unable to open connection to ADB server: java.io.IOException: Can't find adb server on port 5037, IPv4 attempt: Connection refused, IPv6 attempt: Connection refused
01:22:36 D/ddms: Launching '/mnt/c/Users/aoeif/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server' to ensure ADB is running.
01:22:36 D/DeviceMonitor: Unable to open connection to ADB server: java.io.IOException: Can't find adb server on port 5037, IPv4 attempt: Connection refused, IPv6 attempt: Connection refused
01:22:36 D/ddms: Launching '/mnt/c/Users/aoeif/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server' to ensure ADB is running.
01:22:36 D/ddms: '/mnt/c/Users/aoeif/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server' succeeded
01:22:36 I/DeviceMonitor: adb restarted
01:22:36 D/ddms: '/mnt/c/Users/aoeif/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server' succeeded
01:22:36 I/DeviceMonitor: adb restarted
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:inspectClassesForKotlinIC UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:jar UP-TO-DATE
01:22:37 D/DeviceMonitor: Opening adb connection
01:22:37 D/DeviceMonitor: Opening adb connection
01:22:37 D/DeviceMonitor: Unable to open connection to ADB server: java.io.IOException: Can't find adb server on port 5037, IPv4 attempt: Connection refused, IPv6 attempt: Connection refused
01:22:37 D/DeviceMonitor: Unable to open connection to ADB server: java.io.IOException: Can't find adb server on port 5037, IPv4 attempt: Connection refused, IPv6 attempt: Connection refused
01:22:37 D/ddms: Launching '/mnt/c/Users/aoeif/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server' to ensure ADB is running.
01:22:37 D/ddms: Launching '/mnt/c/Users/aoeif/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server' to ensure ADB is running.
01:22:37 D/ddms: '/mnt/c/Users/aoeif/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server' succeeded
01:22:37 D/ddms: '/mnt/c/Users/aoeif/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server' succeeded
01:22:37 I/DeviceMonitor: adb restarted
01:22:37 I/DeviceMonitor: adb restarted

> Task :help

Welcome to Gradle 7.5.1.

To run a build, run gradlew <task> ...

To see a list of available tasks, run gradlew tasks

To see more detail about a task, run gradlew help --task <task>

To see a list of command-line options, run gradlew --help

For more detail on using Gradle, see https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html

For troubleshooting, visit https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
6 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 5 up-to-date
```

I've tried disabling my firewall and antivirus, and also creating a React Native project in the Windows filesystem, thinking it was an inter-system networking problem, but to no avail. I've also tried:

```
export WSL_HOST=$( tail -1 /etc/resolv.conf | cut -d ' ' -f2 )
export ADB_SERVER_SOCKET=tcp:$WSL_HOST:5037
```

It seems that adb is working correctly from WSL2, as I can see the AVD is listed after `adb devices` and reboots after `adb reboot`, but not in the context of being used for React Native.

Answer (score 1):

Could you check if both ADB versions are same on WSL2 and Windows? If not, please install the same version on both and try again.

Comment: I saw a few posts mentioning adb version but didn't quite understand. The only installation of adb (and the rest of the Android development kit) as far as I'm aware is on Windows. I made a link from adb.exe to adb in the system-tools directory so that the executable is Linux recognizable, and that seems to be working correctly. So adb is only executing on Windows.

Comment: Just to be thorough, I checked and received same output on WSL2 and Windows: 1.0.41 version 33.03-8952118

Comment: This answer doesn't provide a working solution to the problem. Please, use comments to the original question if you need more clarification and/or details from the author.